# Things to consider for a sysadmin, and setting up a development network/environment

Tags: untagged

I am creating a development network/environment for development of web applications, and software applications. I am looking to have a system administrator involved with implementation, so I'm creating a rough overview of what kinds of functions should be available, as well as what things the system administrator should do.

The following is a first attempt at what I've thought of. I'd appreciate any additional thoughts/comments that I may have missed!

> **Notes for a system administrator for the network**
>
> Inventory of the network
>      decide static/dynamic for assigning IP addresses
>        -don't forget wireless connected laptops..
>
> handle the security for the network
>      decide what functions are required for the development/test/production systems
>      decide what processes/functions on each server
>
> keep records/notes on all of this
>      -eventually keep the notes in the wiki for the system administrator
>      -restrict the read/usage of this wiki
>
> handle all backup processes
>      establish restore polices for backup procedures
>      establish network/system wide backup procedure/policy for the different servers/functions
>      establish policy for user access to the various services/machines
>      should have a central/master location to handle the login/access
>
> processes
>     -possible implememt sudo policies for system/services
>     establish reverse proxy for web sites
>     establish router port forwarding policies
>     establish tunneling processes (if required)
>     establish single point of router access, which then gets forwarded to other servers as a secure approach... (or devise a different/better approach)
>     create network diagram with servers/functions/IP addresses
>     create central images for the different types of servers that we'll need/have
>     create central rpm/repository for the rpms/net/PXE install..
>     create process to perform PXE installs...
>     define server for Apache test
>     define server for DNS/shcp/Nagios/iptables/security/NFS
>     define server for MySQL/database
>     define server for porj mgmt app
>     define test servers for crawler clients
>     define server for managing the distributed crawler/app
>     define mail server
>     define backup server(s)
>     define redundant strategy for backup/restore data policies

Answer (score 4):

I would span the `handle the security for the network`function at least into the following sub-functions:

- Establishing the hardening baseline for servers (operating systems and software)
- Periodic vulnerability analysis
- Software alerts monitoring and patching where appropriate
- (In a similar fashion) upgrading and/or maintaining upgrade servers (WSUS, apt-dater...)
- Log analysis and centralization (and managing the log repository, with Splunk or a similar software)
- Intrusion detection (maybe centralization of intrusion detection on a platform like OSSIM)

  - Network: snort
  - Host: OSSEC

Answer (score 2):

You need to bring backup and restore more forward.  Look at adding stuff like performing and confirming test restores, defining an offsite strategy, defining and implementing recovery point and recovery time objectives, and so forth.